# "pure virtual function call" Message Box

Tags: c#

One of my C# Winforms applications randomly displays a "**pure virtual function call**" message box. When I click on the ok button of that message box the **application immediately shuts down**.
I cannot find any exception in my application logfiles and the eventlog is empty. Can anybody tell me possible reasons for this crash and how I can further analyse the root cause of the problem? thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you calling an abstract function from a destructor?

Via a certain search engine: http://www.google.com/search?q=pure+virtual+function+call+c%23

Raymond has a pretty detailed response: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/04/28/122037.aspx

Comment: Amusingly, this answer is now the top search result for that search string.