# Handle Pure Virtual Function Call in C#

Tags: c#, c++, exception

I am using C# to run a directshow graph and a third party filter by MainConcept errors with a Pure Virtual Function Call.

Is it possible to handle c++ runtime pure virtual function calls in C# gracefully?

There are no other exceptions provided as a popup displays over the app pointing to the directshow filter. Nothing logged in event viewer either.

Comment: Errors with *what* exception? You didn't provide sufficient information to get a reasonable answer.

Comment: VC++ runtime error. Pure Virtual Function Call.

Comment: Doesn't happen all the time and can't get it to happen in debug... so not sure how much more of an exception I can provide.

Comment: When an error doesn't happen all the time and you can't make it happen in debug mode, you can usually blame dangling pointers. That said, unless you'd give us your full sourcecode (which we won't study) or a short reproducible case, you can't expect us to know more than you.

Comment: How did this get upvoted and I get downvoted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464311/pure-virtual-function-call-message-box

Comment: I don't have MainConcept's source code, it's a third party library. What I'm asking is there a general way to catch this and handle it... like a global exception handler?

Comment: If the error is an exception thrown by the C++ runtime when invoked from .NET, then yes, a `try/catch` block should be able to catch it. However I'm not sure that error is actually an unhandled exception. If you could compile the code, you could just turn off runtime checks. This is not a suggestion though: I don't think errors should be just swallowed in runtime, but they should be corrected.

Comment: There is a try catch around the code in use the entire directshow graph but it doesn't catch it. I believe its an asynchronous routine in the filter because it is used for encoding.

Comment: The error indicates that somewhere, during a constructor or destructor, there's a call to a virtual function that is not implemented (would equate to an `abstract` function definition in C#). It's hard to say why it happens without seeing the code, and as I said, I don't think that's an unhandled exception (but a runtime check that fails and spits that message by default unless compiled without those checks). If you can't fix the code, there's no way to get rid of it, other than writing to Mainconcept and get them to fix it.

Comment: Also, if you *could* catch it or remove the check, your unmanaged memory would be in an undefined state that would more likely crash your application not so much further on

Answer (score 0):

The problem source is in the third party component you have as a binary. It stumbles on certain internal problem, displays the box then terminates the process. You can of course send relevant information to component vendor (MainConcept) so that they possibly fix that on their side.

There is little you can do here except one thing. Apparently the problem is related to certain specific external behavior or data you stream through this component. Examples of this include: specific order of termination calls, ill-formed input, calls from multiple threads. If you happen to see the pattern of what might be causing the problem exactly, then you can possibly prevent the scenario from taking place.